# Why is this allowed to exist as a patent?

Tags: us6370535

This patent [US6370535](http://www.google.com/patents/US6370535.pdf) broadly describes any news release with a headline and content.  It's childishly simple and has absolutely no value. It simply documents the extraordinarily broad and intuitive process of creating a news release.  Why is this a patent?  Why would the USPTO give someone a patent on a generic process?  I'm not a lawyer, but this appears to put any individual or company creating a news release with a headline in a position of infringing on a patent.  I'm baffled.  Please make sense of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The broadest claims do look really broad to me:

> 1. A method for structured generation of a news release, the method comprising:
>
>    a. separately specifying content of each of a plurality of pre-determined sections of the news release, the predetermined sections and their ordering determining in part a desired format for the news release;
>
>    b. storing, in a digital storage medium, the content specified for each of the sections; and
>
>    c. assembling the news release by retrieving from the storage medium each of the stored sections in a manner consistent with the desired format.

But It does has more substance than just any news release. It is a **method for producing news releases** in a predetermined format based on pulling the ingredients together from multiple databases. The fleshed out idea behind it is a menu driven Q and A with explanations and hints to help one produce a press release with a particular set of facts and points. Not earth-shattering, but probably new and non-obvious at the time. The examiner looked at nine other, earlier patents in the field and a similar number of magazine articles and found this doing something none of those did.  Later claims, like 13 have more meat.

Still, claim 1 is really broad on its face and might have a harder time standing up than many of the dependent claims. (I assume it was granted at a time when the patentability pendulum had swung far to one side.)